# Print all options in Drop Down in Google Sheet using Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Does any one have any script where I can print all the options in Drop Down using App Script in Google Sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the option values from the DataValidation of the dropdown list type using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I think that `getDataValidation()` and `getCriteriaValues()` can be used for achieving your goal.

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, the option values are retrieved from the DataValidation in the cell "A1".

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const dataValidation = sheet.getRange("A1").getDataValidation();
const check = [SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE, SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST];
if (dataValidation && check.includes(dataValidation.getCriteriaType())) {
  const [criteria] = dataValidation.getCriteriaValues();
  const res = criteria.toString() == "Range" ? criteria.getValues() : criteria;
  console.log(res)
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the option values from multiple DataValidations in the range, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const dataValidations = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).getDataValidations();
    const check = [SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE, SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST];
    const res = dataValidations.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        if (c && check.includes(c.getCriteriaType())) {
          const [criteria] = c.getCriteriaValues();
          ar.push({row: i + 1, column: j + 1, values: criteria.toString() == "Range" ? criteria.getValues() : criteria});
        }
      });
      return ar;
    }, []);
    console.log(res)
  ```
- In the case of `getDataValidations()`, when the drop down list has empty value, `getDataRange()` cannot retrieve the range. So in this sample, `getMaxRows()` and `getMaxColumns()` are used. By this, above 2nd script can retrieves all DataValidations of the dropdown list type in a sheet.

#### References:

- [getDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidation)
- [Class DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)
- [getDataValidations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidations)