# Is there a way to automatically print all the options inside a drop-down menu in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

This question has been asked before, but upon checking the answers and doing some more research, I was unable to come up with a solution that worked.

I have a spreadsheet with a drop-down menu (data validation) and I am looking for a more streamlined way to print my billing form with all the options inside my drop-down menu which is essentially a list with all my patients' names. This would save me a lot of time every month for invoices.

This is the link to my spreadsheet:
[Patient Billing Form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vStIBoIyQxOILtJYM_jTzqPm3_2y0m7LwPbTBWTRvedXOtOE_53rcbKQUzc4eSk-PAGBJJLlEEyFq_C/pubhtml)

I also tried to work around the source code provided by Xfanatical, (SEE HERE: [XFANATICAL](https://xfanatical.com/blog/how-to-print-all-options-in-a-drop-down-list-in-google-sheets/), as well as [Other Stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64203010/print-all-options-in-drop-down-in-google-sheet-using-script), but even that didnt work.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? and please forgive my rambling.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you interested in a solution that involves you writing some code?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my incoherence.  The whole point of this post was based on the Google Script App Editor. Code would be greatly appreciated, Cooper!!

Comment: Then I recommend doing a little more research and write some code and post it in your question.

Comment: if you don't want to do some extra research and write some code is fine with me. But please give more details on what you want to achieve. Where is that drop down menu? the file you shared does not show it. What do you mean by `print the form` ? You want to generate a pdf out of it or what? I would advice you to follow the advice of Cooper, but if you really don't want to do some extra research then at least provide more details on what you want to achieve. Provide screenshots or an actual sheet (instead of an html overview of the sheet itself).

Comment: By the way there is one  way that I can think of but it's not necessarily an easy way to do it and as far as printing goes I'm happy with printing it on my screen.  However you wish to get it onto paper would be up to you.  So I'd probably wouldn't suggest it unless you provided a little more information as to why and how you might wish to use the information.

Answer (score 0):

**Finding the Code that Created a Menu**

I'm not suggesting that this is a complete answer but depending upon how bad you want the information this tool will find it.  It prints out the all of the functions that in the page where the menu you name was created.  This giving  you access to all the items in the menu.  A prettier version of the output could be had with a little extra effort that I don't wish to provide at this point. It would probably involved use regular expressions to extra the exact information.

```
function displayAllItemsInMenu() {
  const scriptId=ScriptApp.getScriptId();
  const url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId + "/content";
  const options = {"method":"get","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  let data=JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Menu Title","Please enter the name of the menu", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    const title=resp.getResponseText();
    const files=data.files;
    let found="";
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
      let file=files[i];    
      let s=JSON.stringify(file.source);
      if(file.type="SERVER_JS" && s.indexOf(title)!=-1) {
        found+=file.source;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(found.length>0) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<textarea cols="80" rows="40">' + found + '</textarea>'), "Found")
    }
  }
}
```

You will have to provide the name of the file and you will also have to enable the Google Apps Script Rest API.

This narrows down the results but it is sensitive to how the author built the menus.

```
function displayAllItemsInMenu() {
  const scriptId=ScriptApp.getScriptId();
  const url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId + "/content";
  const options = {"method":"get","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  let data=JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Menu Title","Please enter the name of the menu", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    const title=resp.getResponseText();
    const files=data.files;
    let found="";
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
      let file=files[i];    
      let s=JSON.stringify(file.source);
      if(file.type="SERVER_JS" && s.indexOf(title)!=-1) {
        found+=file.source;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(found.length>0) {
      let s=found.match(/\.addItem.*/g).map(function(e){return e.slice(8);});
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<textarea cols="80" rows="40">' + s.join('\n') + '</textarea>').setWidth(1000), "Found")
    }
  }
}
```