# How to clip list in cell in spreadsheet with Google Apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Images:  [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfk9e.png)  ,  [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s4qf.png)

I made a list as you can see in the image1. You can understand the list better if you look at image2.

The list is in cell `A1`. I want to copy this list to cell `B1` with google app script. `getValue()`, `getValues()` don't work. These commands take the data selected in the list. But I want to get all the data on the list. Is there a command that I can get all the data in the list?

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
  var spreadSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");


  var listValue = sheetName.getRange("A1").getValue();
  sheetName.getRange("B1").setValue(listValue);

}
```

This code prints only the selected value in the list into cell `B1`.

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64203010 If the list is retrieved from the DataValidation in cell "A1" and put to the cell "B1", please put the script of `sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(res.join(","))` to the last line in the if statement in the 1st sample script of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64203787 . But if I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: I've tried. He piled up all the data on the list. But he wrote it to cell B1 in array format. It did not create a list in cell B1. in B1 cell `apple,orange,strawberry`

Comment: How can I list in cell B1 with the array [apple, orange, strawberry]? The problem is solved if I list it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I understood that I misunderstood your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. And, now I noticed that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to copy the data validation and set it to the destination cell. Also don't forget to copy the value if you need that to be the same as well.

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
  var spreadSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var dataValidation = sheetName.getRange("A1").getDataValidation();
  var listValue = sheetName.getRange("A1").getValue();
  sheetName.getRange("B1").setDataValidation(dataValidation); // make B1 a dropdown like A1
  sheetName.getRange("B1").setValue(listValue); // set value of B1 same with value of A1
}
```

#### Sample Input:

[image: input]

#### Sample Output:

[image: output]